# How much would a weapon cost that grants advantage on damage rolls?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, pricing

Given the answers to these questions:

[Advantage on damage rolls - is it still balanced?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103475/advantage-on-damage-rolls-is-it-still-balanced)

['Advantage' or 'Disadvantage' on damage rolls](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/188576/advantage-or-disadvantage-on-damage-rolls)

What should a weapon cost that grants advantage on damage rolls, but no other enhancements?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### 101-500 gp.

Ilmari Karonen analyzed the average damage increase for such weapons [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/188580/62294). Here are the results:

| Die | Normal | Advantage | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| d4 | 2.5 | 3.125 | +0.625 |
| d6 | 3.5 | 4.4722 | +0.9722 |
| d8 | 4.5 | 5.8125 | +1.3125 |
| d10 | 5.5 | 7.15 | +1.65 |
| d12 | 6.5 | 8.4861 | +1.9861 |
| highest of two 2d6 rolls | 7 | 8.37 | +1.37 |

A +2 magic weapon guarantees a flat +2 increase to damage, so all of these weapons will yield an inferior damage improvement to a +2 magic weapon, *without providing the bonus to hit provided by the magic weapon.* +2 magic weapons are *Rare* magic items, and all of these would be strictly worse, so these weapons should value somewhere in the range of *Uncommon* magic items, which is 101-500 gp (see the ["Magic Item Rarity" table](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/treasure#MagicItemRarity) in the DMG). From here, it makes sense to scale the value somewhere within this range according to the damage improvement given, possibly taking into account that the weapons are not actually magical, and so would not overcome resistance to nonmagical slashing, piercing, or bludgeoning.

Note, if a feature adds additional damage dice to an attack's damage, such as the Rogue's Sneak Attack, it should not be rolled at advantage, as the improvement can get out of hand.

Comment: Conferring advantage does more than just straight potential damage increase - there are quite a few features that trigger where it can substantially be increased (rogue, I'm looking at you.)

Comment: @NautArch the querent's only asking about advantage for damage rolls, which isn't really a thing in 5e, but there are features that emulate something akin to that (i.e. Savage Attacker feat).

Comment: @Pyrotechnical Savage Attacker immediately came to mind for me, too -- particularly the fact that it only works once per turn. This weapon ability would work on every attack in a turn, and furthermore, because advantage on damage isn't _really_ a thing, there's never going to be _dis_advantage imposed on the roll to balance it out. What I can't decide is, does that show the weapon ability is being undervalued in the answer, or does it merely reiterate how bad Savage Attacker is?

Comment: @screamline The weapons here aren’t even as good as +1 magic weapons, so no, I haven’t undervalued them.

Comment: @screamline, I think it says more about the effects of allowing players to easily purchase magic items. Also, it could be argued that Savage Attacker stacks with this, a situation I hadn't considered.